# Use of noun vs. adjective in store signs

Tags: nouns, adjectives

I saw the following on a store sign in a foreign country.
EXCELLENCE IN HAND DRIP COFFEE

Isn't it better to use adjective as in
EXCELLENT HAND DRIP COFFEE
?

Comment: It's ad copy -- you use whatever you believe will attract customers.  Even misspellings and fractured grammar are "fair", if they do the job.

Answer (score 1):

*mmmmm hand drip coffee....mmmmmm*

By starting the phrase with the noun, they are indicating that they provide excellence, or are known for their excellence. This is a stronger statement than just saying "Excellent Hand Drip Coffee" because it suggests that someone somewhere believes it already, and gives them some reputation.

Answer (score 0):

A sentence fragment that begins "Excellence in .... "   is retailing/marketing cant.

It implies  "You can expect excellence in {something} from us" or "We are known for excellence in {something}".